# Spring Boot with AWS Cognito Hosting issues

Tags: java, spring, amazon-cognito

I am following this tutorial
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito

When using a callback URL/ redirect uri of http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito and running locally everything works fine.

When I deploy this code with the callback URL/ redirect uri of https://{myAWSHostedURL}/login/oauth2/code/cognito and login no longer works. Typically I get a DNS cannot resolve issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhpjv.jpg

I am hosting my domain on ROUTE53 with a DNS entry pointing from my domain name to the Elastic Beanstalk Hostname of the site.

If there is any other information I can provide I will happily do so.

Edit: Added Workflow of what I am trying to do.

As a user I can navigate to domain.com
Click Sign In
AWS Cognito Hosted UI sign in form pops up
Enter Credentials
Redirected to home page as authenticated user.

Comment: What are you using for the AWS host? It looks like that name isn't resolved; find out why that isn't working first, before you look at your cognito errors.

Comment: The domain host is: https://development-service-checkin.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com

I am using https://subdomain.domain.com/login/oauth2/code/cognito as the Callback URL(s) and in Spring at application.yml as the redirect-uri

Comment: subdomain.domain.com doesn't look like a valid hostname ...

Comment: Thank you for assisting so changing that to just domain.com/login/oauth2/code/cognito results in DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN this was the same error i was seeing with subdomain.domain.com/login/oauth2/code/cognito

Comment: OK but the point is the 'subdomain.domain.com' is supposed to be replaced with /your/ site, not a random example site.

Comment: I am redirecting to a site that is active. development.furrerindustries.com